Queue table on SQL Server using In-Memory OLTP
We have an exising message queue solution build around a table, let's call it queue. We do have a number of processors that can both add, read and update records on the queue. Until now this have worked well enough even if, from fimt to time have shown some contention. Now when we are scalling up with more queue records and more processors we have started to see serious contention issues.
As one way of solving this we are looking into migrating the queue table to In-Memory OLTP. We are planning to use schema and data durability. In theory this should be ideal for something like a queue table. Unfortuantely we can't migrate without code changes as the current solution is using READPAST and ROWLOCK query hints that are not available for memory optimized tables. When removing the hints and try to run the code we are as expected getting error 41302 as the different processors tries to process the same record.
We are using SQL Server 2022 with RCSI turned on, and MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT is enabled. A simplified presenation of our current solutions looks like this.
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT TOP 1 
    @queue_Id = q.Id
 FROM dbo.queue AS q WITH (READPAST)
WHERE q.DateProcessed IS NULL 
  AND q.DateScheduled <=  GetUTCDATE()
ORDER BY q.Priority ASC;

UPDATE dbo.queue WITH (ROWLOCK)
   SET DateProcessed = GetUTCDATE()
 WHERE Id = @queue_Id 
   AND DateProcessed IS NULL;

COMMIT;

Anyone having some ideas how you can get this type of queue working with In-Memory OLTP?

Using a table as a queue is the actual problem, not locking. this should be ideal for something like a queue table not at all, in-memory is meant for high throughput scenarios, not queueing. If you really want queues, use the native queues provided by Service Broker. Even that won't come near RabbitMQ or Kafka though.

@PanagiotisKanavos, than you for the comment. I'm sure that Service Broker and other queue providers many times are a better solution. Still you are also pointing out that in-memory is meant for high throughput scenarios and that is what we now have as the old solution have problem couping with the number of records added and processed on the queue. Not sure if we are at this stage ready for totally refator this to use something like Service Broker.

if you have multiple processors ,does the order of processing really matters? Or the "top 1" thing? Sounds like it should be enough so not everyone takes the same ID more than once

Interesting idea, and in some circumstances that could work. Unfortuantely in our case the priority is important and we need to maske sure that we processes the high priority first.

One way to reduce some of the contention is to use a more standardized Queue syntax, with the SELECT and UPDATE merged into one. This obviates the need for an explicit transaction.
UPDATE q
SET DateProcessed = GetUTCDATE(),
    @queue_Id = q.Id
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1) q.*
    FROM dbo.queue q WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
    WHERE q.DateProcessed IS NULL 
      AND q.DateScheduled <= SYSUTCDATETIME()
    ORDER BY q.Priority ASC
) q;

You also must make sure to have a proper index in place.
CREATE INDEX ix ON dbo.queue (Priority, Id)
INCLUDE (DateScheduled, DateProcessed)
WHERE (DateProcessed IS NULL);

If it's much more likely that you will get very few rows just by filtering on DateScheduled then put that first in the index key. It's pointless putting both DateScheduled and Priority in the key, as you can't have an inequality and ordering seek at the same time.
CREATE INDEX ix ON dbo.queue (DateScheduled DESC, Id)
INCLUDE (Priority, DateProcessed)
WHERE (DateProcessed IS NULL);


Thank you for your suggstion. Looking interesting, and I'm sure that it will be more effective then our current solution. As this can't be used for in-memory due to the lock hints, do you suggest this as an alternative to migrating to in-memory?

Yes, I would certainly try it. Barring that, move to an entirely different queueing system such as some kind of EventBus. SQL Server isn't really built for this kind of thing.

@seanb Given there is only one row being affected, you can just use scalar variables as I showed. There is no need for another table.

Ah yeah sorry @Charlieface, that makes sense.

@Charlieface I will look into if that could work for us. Seems like that we should get a performance increase by it.
